# RxJs combining different and perform different actions based on stream

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs

```
const f1$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('firstName', data => ob.next(data)));
const f2$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('lastName', data => ob.next(data)));
const f3$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('middleName', data => ob.next(data));

const mainObj$ = of({ address: 'abc street' });

combineLatest([f1$, f2$, f3$, mainObj$], (f, l, m, dataBlock) => {

    return R.compose(addFirstName(f), addLastName(l), addMiddleName(m))(dataBlock);

}).pipe(

    flatMap(data => this.someHttpService.save(data)),
    pluck('id')
).subscribe(id => console.log(`user ${id} saved successfully`));
```

How can I remove compose and just use rxjs  to achieve same functionality.

Also I want f1$, f2$, f3$ to act like behaviour subject, because i want to save user with only address also.

My main objective to manipulate the mainObj object based on f1$, f2$, f3$.

Witch combineLatest how can I find  out which observable was triggered, so that I can apply only that operation.
eg if **f1$** was trigger I will just apply addFirstNameFn to mainObj instead of calling them all. (addFirstName, addLastName, addMiddleName).

Comment: If you want to react differently to `f1$`, `f2$` and `f3$`, why need to combine them? Just subscribe to three individual observables and have your `mainObj` react to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can next() the data as well as its handler and use the attached handler to excute like below

```js
const f1$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('firstName', data => ob.next({data,func:(data)=>{})));
const f2$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('lastName', data => ob.next({data,func:(data)=>{})));
const f3$ = Observable.create(ob => this.eventService.on('middleName', data =>ob.next({data,func:(data)=>{})));

const mainObj$ = of({ address: 'abc street' });

combineLatest([f1$, f2$, f3$, mainObj$], (f, l, m, dataBlock) => {

f1$.func(f1$.data) ...
m$.func(m$.data)... 
l$.func(l$.data)...

}).pipe(

    flatMap(data => this.someHttpService.save(data)),
    pluck('id')
).subscribe(id => console.log(`user ${id} saved successfully`));
```

Comment: is it related to your question?

Comment: ya its related to rxjs